# Webpack: silence output

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to know if there's a configuration option to tell webpack to only log the "important information" to the terminal. Pretty much just errors and warnings, not all of this:

[image: output of terminal with webpack]

There's just so much output! Would love to suppress the common stuff and only have webpack output the warnings/errors. Would like a solution for `webpack`, `webpack-dev-server`, and `karma-webpack`.

*Note*: I tried `noInfo: true` and `quiet: true` but that didn't seem to do the trick.

---

*Edit:* I'm thinking this may not be possible, so I've created an issue on github: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1191

Comment: Looks like on the command line the `noInfo` option is actually the inverse of `--info`, which defaults to `true` so if you run `webpack-dev-server --info false` it should get you closer to where you want to be.

Comment: That appears to do it for webpack-dev-server... Now if only I could get it for my tests :-)

Comment: If anyone's curious, here's what I execute now: `NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --content-base app/ --port 8888 --colors --progress --info false`

Comment: This works as well: `NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --content-base app/ --port 8888 --colors --progress --no-info`

Comment: Is there any chance to provide these options via the webpack.config.js?
All I see in the code is how the options are read from argv

Comment: Yeah, me too @LukasZech, I'd like to be able to add this to my config for karma. Original question still not answered on this one. I don't believe it's currently possible, but I have an issue for it: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1191

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't know when this feature was added, but I just noticed in [the docs](https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack) that you can add a `webpackMiddleware` property and on that you can specify `noInfo: true`. Doing this removes all the noise! But you still see output when there are errors. Yay!

Answer (score 68):

In my webpack config, Doing this reduced my incremental build time by 8 seconds and silenced output. The main one is `chunks: false`

Play with it to fit your needs

```
module.exports = {
 devServer: {
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    hash: false,
    version: false,
    timings: false,
    assets: false,
    chunks: false,
    modules: false,
    reasons: false,
    children: false,
    source: false,
    errors: false,
    errorDetails: false,
    warnings: false,
    publicPath: false
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Works great! The key ones to disable are `hash, version, timings, assets, chunks`.

Answer (score 59):

Actually, these two work great.

```
stats: 'errors-only',
```

at the end of the exported object.

One could also use `stats: 'minimal',` it only outputs when errors or new compilation happen. Read more from the [official documentation of Webpack.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/)

Answer (score 17):

You've got the `--display` option that enables you to choose a level of information quantity you want displayed.

From `webpack --help`:

```
--display: Select display preset
[string] [choices: "", "verbose", "detailed", "normal", "minimal", "errors-only", "none"]
```

---

If you want to configure the informations displayed more precisely, you can also configure your webpack with the [stats](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/) field in your `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 10):

These days `noInfo` `quiet` and `stats` have been replaced by [infrastructureLogging](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#level) in the root of your Webpack config:

```
// webpack.config.js
...
infrastructureLogging: {
  level: 'error',
},
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the `webpack-dev-middleware` you can throw the `noInfo: true` in an object as the second parameter. *Also assuming you also have a node/express server running.*

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: I'm posting this for other people with the similar issue on a slightly different configuration because Google Search is leading them here.

Comment: You can also add `noInfo: true` to the `devServer` configuration item in webpack.config.js.

Comment: Only one that worked for me.  Also works on webpackMiddleware.  Thank you, crap output was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 9):

## Webpack

```
  ...
  stats: {
    modules: false,
  },
  ...
```

## Dev Server

```
  ...
  devServer: {
    stats: {
      modules: false,
    },
  },
  ...
```

### Reference

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

Answer (score 4):

What you're interested in here is [`stats`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/) [module](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#stats-options) (part) of the [Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.12.0/lib/Stats.js). Basically, it's this module that produces [the output](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/v3.0.8/bin/cli.js#L500-L504). The output by default mostly contains list of assets, and list of modules. You can hide modules with `--hide-modules` directive. Regarding assets, no similar option exists. But there are [presets](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.12.0/lib/Stats.js#L1330-L1392). You can specify preset with `--display` option. And preset that hides assets is... `none`.

There is another way to influence stats: `webpack.config.js`. Add `stats: {assets: false, modules: false}` to reduce output significantly. Or `stats: 'none'` to silence Webpack entirely. Not that I recommend it. Generally `errors-only` is a way to go. To make it affect `webpack-dev-server` put it under `devServer` key.

Webpack 2.x doesn't have `--display` option. And the only way to hide modules is `--hide-modules` switch. By that I mean that specifying `stats: 'errors-only'` or `stats: {modules: false}` in config has no effect. Since [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v2.7.0/bin/webpack.js#L221-L224) piece of code overrides all that.

For `webpack-dev-server` there are also [`--no-info`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-noinfo-) and [`--quiet`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-quiet-) options.

Some more insight into how it works. `webpack-cli` creates [`outputOptions` object](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/v3.0.8/bin/cli.js#L293-L434). When compilation finishes, it converts stats to [string](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/v3.0.8/bin/cli.js#L500) and [outputs](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/v3.0.8/bin/cli.js#L504) it. `Stats.toString` converts [stats](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.12.0/lib/Stats.js#L709) to [json](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.12.0/lib/Stats.js#L93-L698), then converts [json](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.12.0/lib/Stats.js#L711) to [string](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.12.0/lib/Stats.js#L714-L1328). Here you can see [the defaults](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.12.0/lib/Stats.js#L137-L214).

Answer (score 2):

Recommend stats config below, this will keep significant logs and remove useless info.

```
stats: {
  cached: false,
  cachedAssets: false,
  chunks: false,
  chunkModules: false,
  chunkOrigins: false,
  modules: false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Webpack 5 I had to remove stats from devServer and add it as a base config property.
All the relevant stats can be found here for additional configuration https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#infrastructurelogging

**The following worked for me:** *(I use friendly-errors)*

```
{
  stats: 'errors-only',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: 'none',
  },
  devServer:{
    // other config
  }
}
```

You can also be more specific about what to display using an object.

```
{
  stats: {
    entrypoints: false,
    colors: true,
    assets: false,
    chunks: false,
    modules: false,
  },
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: 'none',
  },
  devServer:{
    // other config
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Webpack API directly, and you're calling `stats.toString()`, then you can pass parameters to keep down the noise:

```javascript
webpack(config).watch(100, (err, stats) => {
  console.log(stats.toString({chunks: false}))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Webpack v5

The "most silent" configuration:

```js
infrastructureLogging: { level: 'error' },
stats: 'minimal',
```

Docs: [`infrastructureLogging`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#level), [`stats`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats-presets).

Answer (score 0):

`webpack --stats errors-only` is the command line flag you probably want (v5).