# How to hide webpack-dev-server log?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Once webpack-dev-server start, the console will output:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://127.0.0.1:3002/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from ...
```

However, I am not willing to display the above log to users, how to hide them?

Comment: Who is your "user" that'll see that…? The dev server is a developer tool…

Comment: My teammates and I  :-)

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756804/webpack-silence-output

Comment: @AlexandarZaharyan I've tried `noInfo: true`, `quiet: true`, and nearly all `stats` properties, but still not work, could you please point out the detail configuration?

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
devServer: {
  client: {
    logging: 'none'
  }
}
```

doc: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#logging

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming here in regards to **webpack-dev-server v4**,

As per the [v4 migration guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md):

> log, logLevel, logTime, quiet, noInfo, and reporter options were removed without replacement, now we use [built-in logger](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#infrastructurelogging).

So you need to add this to your Webpack config:

```
infrastructureLogging: {
  level: 'error',
},
```

Comment: I added it but still I get console on browser with lines line :
Compiled with warnings:

Answer (score 2):

in my case

```js
const devServer = new webpackDevServer(complier ,{
  // quiet: true,
  noInfo: true,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  clientLogLevel: 'silent'
})
```

set `noInfo` work well. but with `quiet` wds log still show, I dont know why

Answer (score 2):

#### Webpack v5

The "most silent" configuration:

```js
infrastructureLogging: { level: 'error' },
stats: 'minimal',
```

Docs: [`infrastructureLogging`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#level), [`stats`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats-presets).

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
stats: 'errors-only'
```

in your webpack-dev-server config