# How can I hide webpack-dev-server on browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, frontend

Recently I created a react app with the `npx create-react-app` command.

The thing is that until know, every time I created an app like this, nothing was displayed on the browser console after running npm start, but now I have this console.log:

```
 [webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement enabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled.
```

I just want to hide those kind of messages because to me are unnecessary at the moment.
I have search few posts and other websites but I can't solve this problem.

Most of the answers I have reads talks about create a webpack file and make configuration inside, but it shouldn't be necessary.
Also I have tried in the package-log to add some lines which I found on this post: [How to hide webpack-dev-server log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930130/how-to-hide-webpack-dev-server-log),  but it didn't work.

To say I have nothing deleted from the folder after created a react app, so it comes like this.
Hope somebody could help.

Comment: What's wrong with this useful debugging message?

Comment: It's nothing wrong, but I wanted to keep the console clear and just displaying errors or console.log() and it just appeared like that. I don't know anything yet about webpack and I have no idea why is showing it on console.

Comment: You are using `create-react-app` so you would need to use `npm run eject` and then edit the config as they answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930130/how-to-hide-webpack-dev-server-log). But I would just leave it as it is. I don't understand why the development tool would have to be exactly as we want it.