# React Webpack loglevel:webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react project using webpack so there is one problem when I am adding a product in a cart am storing the value in localcal storage but there is one problem with data also store loglevel:webpack-dev-server in localStorage.
So please help me how to remove loglevel:webpack-dev-server in localStorage.

Comment: Whenever a question is asked in this community please post required code, for example in your question people need webpack config to help you please update with the webpack config and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Okay the problem is that's amountOfProducts 1 
product_9 {"id":"9","thumbnail":"https://assets.myntassets.com/h_1440,q_100,w_1080/v1/assets/images/8593217/2019/4/9/de2c21f3-6731-4c29-9369-692a486a1b8c1554802772926-Samsung-Gear-IconX-Black-Cord-free-Fitness-Earbuds-256155480-1.jpg","name":"Gear IconX Black Cord-free Fitness Earbuds","price":13990,"amount":1} 
loglevel:webpack-dev-server SILENT, how to remove permanently from my local storage only that one loglevel:webpack-dev-server SILENT

Comment: you might want to check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756804/webpack-silence-output, your question might be already answered